# Which among the following String Objects will be ready for garbage collection?

Tags: java, string, object, garbage-collection

I'm a little confused when it comes to Strings constant pool and heap, I want to understand when does a string object be eligible for garbage collection, so taking the below code into consideration which among the following Strings objects will be ready for garbage collection in java?

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = new String("hey");
        String s2 = s1;
        String s3 = "hey";
        String s4 = "hey";
        String s5 = new String("guys");
        String s6 = "guys";
        String s7 = "guYs";
        s1 = s1.concat("world");
        s7 = null;
        s8 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will be ready when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: You have variables such as 's1' and these are pointers (in java speak, 'references'). They are like a treasure map: They aren't the treasure themselves, they merely hold direction to where the treasure is.

In this example, variables are treasure maps, strings are treasures.

The above example has a grand total of only 7 treasures:

"hey", "guys", "guYs", "world" – these 4 treasures are created as your class is loaded, because they are inside your source code literally. guys and guYs are obviously different strings.

the 5th treasure is the string created with `new String("hey")` - this passes a reference to the treasure `"hey"` to the string constructor. All constructors ALWAYS make new treasure, even if its a pointless exercise here (strings cannot be changed, so what's the point, right? Just, the rule is: calling `new` means new treasure, so new treasure is made). Now the treasure map `s1` points at unique treasure that so happens to look rather a lot like treasure `"hey"`.

`s2 = s1` is merely copying a treasure map. It leads to the same treasure as s1 does.

`s3` becomes a treasure map that points to existing treasure `"hey"`. It is different treasure than what s1 and s1 point to.

`s4` becomes the same treasure map as s3.

`s5` and `s6` are a copy of the `s1` vs. `s3` situation: 2 treasures.

`s7` is the same as s3/s4/s6.

Then the `s1` treasure is found (`s1.` - the dot is: Take this treasure map and find the treasure), and then the treasure is asked to perform the method `concat`, passing to it a reference to a different treasure (`"world"`). The implementation of concat ends up making yet another treasure (it'll read "heyworld"), and returns a treasure map pointing at this new treasure. You then toss away the treasure map pointing at `"hey"` (but note that this doesn't modify s2 at all, which still points at the `"hey"` treasure), and replaces it with this new treasure map leading to `"heyworld"`.

You finally change `s7` to be a blank treasure map leading nowhere, and then write a compiler error as s8 doesn't exist.

At this point in the code, let's see how the 7 treasures can still be found:

"hey" - yes, via s3 and s4. which are still pointing at it. And more to the point. they'll always be 'findable'; all you'd have to do is run this main method which can happen anytime. Strings literally written into java files do not go away.

"guys" - via s6.

"guYs" - seemingly not findable at all but, as I said, string literals never go away.

The copy "guys": still via s5.

"heyworld" - yes, s1 is pointing at it.

The copy "hey": Nope, not findable at all. This treasure is 'unreachable'.

In basis, then, the hey-copy is now garbage collectible and nothing else is.

The 7 treasure *maps* are not collectable entities; these things exist on stack and will disappear immediately without cost the moment the method exits.

The way local variables work on-stack is a bit strange: At the class level they are translated to unnamed slots. The details are complex, but suffice to say that it is possible to have a seemingly unreferenced thing still existing in a slot someplace. You can't be sure until the method truly exits, at which point all the local vars (which, in this example, are all treasure maps) immediately disappear.

Also, in practice, garbage collection doesn't kick in until muuuch later. Unreferenced treasures will be stuck in the sand for a long time. The fastest way to deal with them is to just leave them in the sand. As long as the beach is big enough there is no point cleaning up the beach. The topic of GC is much, much more complicated, but as a quick lesson on it: It won't happen until much later, and that is good.

Answer (score -1):

It works like this.

Every string created with `new` operator will get memory from heap space. So `new String("a") == new String("a")` is `false`.

Literals without `new` operator get a place in string pool. So `"a" == "a"` is `true`.

With your code I would says s1, s2, s5, s7 are ready for GC.
s3, s4, s6 are declared as literal, so they be stores in string pool.

Comment: s1, s2, s5, and s7 are all local variables. Those exist on stack and the notion of garbage collection simply does not apply to them.

Comment: The objects pointed at BY those variables are ALL not collectable because OP wrote a bad example. Once the method exits completely, obviously (as nothing is stored in fields anywhere), ALL the non-stringpool strings become collectible.

Comment: I think the question was meant more globally. You are right that local variables are put on stack but I think the code is just a snippet to visualize the problem/question.

Comment: Maybe @mohammed-abbas write another, maybe with instance fields instead of local variables...